# rsync error permissions denied

Tags: linux, ssh

Trying to rsync files from one server to another getting a

```
ubuntu@xx-xxx-xx-xx-xx:~$ rsync -i "xxxxxXXX.pem" -anv webapps ubuntu@xx.xx.xxx.xx:/home/ubuntu/
Permission denied (publickey).
rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (0 bytes received so far) [sender]
rsync error: unexplained error (code 255) at io.c(226) [sender=3.1.1]
```

I can ssh into the server with `ssh -i "xxxxxxx.pem" ubuntu@xx.xxx.xxx.xx`

the permissions for the key are `600`

```
-rw-------  1 ubuntu ubuntu    1696 Feb  1 06:00 xxxxxxxx.pem
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`rsync` is using the `-i` switch for different option than `ssh`. If you need to specify the identity file for `rsync`, use `-e` switch to provide the option directly to the `ssh`:

```
rsync -e "ssh -i xxxxxXXX.pem" -anv webapps ubuntu@xx.xx.xxx.xx:/home/ubuntu/
```